# ASP MVC 5 WebAPI vs Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having some difficulties understanding the difference between ASP.Net MVC WebAPI Controllers (System.Web.Http.ApiController) and @Ajax.ActionLink (PartialViews).

As my knowledge of MVC 5 and razor is not very profound I wonder why I should use ApiController (except for the obvious reason, when I have an external application that requests data from my webapi).

My requirement is to easily do ajax AND leverage the built-in mechanisms like validation and such. 
At this time I use WebApi and jQuery - which works pretty well, but on the other hand i have to do all the exception handling (ie. validation) manually again.

Any advice?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. MVC and webAPI are two different things. Actionlinks are even more different. A comparison between these "two" things isn't useful.

Comment: I am using MVC 5 - WebApi Controllers are a valid option there, I think. http://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/partial-view-using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-5-loads-into-a-new-page/ explains how to use AJAX.ActionLink - Are there any new options on how to do ajax in MVC5?

Comment: You can use webapi controllers in an mvc application but in mvc5 they should be kept separate because of the potential for routing collisions. As far as ajax goes your link seems accurate.